# Divide a negative with a positive

Tags: assembly, division

Assume the following code:

```
mov eax, 0
sub eax, 2

xor edx, edx
idiv base
```

where `base` equals to 8 (defined as `const int base = 8`).

As a result, I expect to get 0 in `eax` and 2 (or −2) in `edx`. However, the result of the division is a big long number. Most likely, it is caused by overflow in `eax` registry, when I subtract 2 from it. I think `eax` is interpreted by `idiv` operation as `unsigned int`. How do I perform this division properly?

I code in Visual Studio 2013 on x64 system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual reason: `edx` is supposed to be the "upper half" of a 64bit dividend. So if you have a negative number, `edx` can not be zero (at least the sign bit must be set, otherwise it's just not negative), and if you had a 32bit signed number, you have to sign-extend it into `edx:eax`.

Which is what the `cdq` instruction does, so it's easy:

```
mov eax, -2

cdq
idiv base
```

Answer (score 3):

Most probably the issue is the following:
After the subtraction the value in EAX will be -2 represented in two's complement: 0xFFFF FFFE
If you want to represent -2 on 64 bit you should have: 0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFE
Because you are setting EDX to be 0, you will have the value 0x0000 0000 FFFF FFFE = 65534 instead of -2

You will have to set EDX to be 0xFFFF FFFF in case of a negative number and to 0 in case of a positive number.