# "Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)" error when dividing by negative value in Assembly

Tags: c, x86, nasm, division

I have written out a small assembly program that divides two numbers, then displays the results through C `printf` function. The program asks for user input for the numbers, then does division as so:

```
mov rax, r14 ;r14 holds the numerator
cqo
mov rbx, r13 ;r13 holds the divisor
idiv rbx
mov r12, rax ;place divided answer into r12
mov r11, rdx ;place remainder from rdx into r11
```

Later printing out the values with:

```
mov rax, 0
mov rdi, outputresult ;outputresult defined as "The quotient of %ld divided by %ld is %ld with remainder %ld."
mov rsi, rsp
mov rsi, r14
mov rdx, rbx
mov rcx, r12
mov r8, r11
call printf
```

As is evident, I moved all values into their respective "calling" register to display the values correctly. This functions perfectly, except when the divisor (`r13`) is a negative number, I get the error stated before (`Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped`).

The program continues to run regardless, and actually displays the correct values no matter if the divisor is negative or positive. However, I wish to get rid of the error which always appears right before the program finishes running. I can provide any further code if I am missing anything crucial.

Comment: Did you debug your code? Which instruction triggers the error?

Comment: Yes, I debugged it. It claims the error happens in `divfunc()` which is the name of the function from my C file that directs to the assembly file where all this calculation is done (i.e. assembly file is headed with `divfunc:`).

Comment: before `idiv rbx` add this command: `cdq`, sign extend

Comment: [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385132/divide-a-negative-with-a-positive)

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately no luck. Same error appears.

Comment: Which error? provide complete codes, i want to test on my machine.

Comment: Well, I meant on which assembly instruction since you suspect your assembly code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. To summarize, I initially pushed `r14` as a qword by doing `push qword r14` after saving the user's input into `r14`.

What I did to fix the issue, was do `push qword 0` to avoid pushing `r14` as a qword (which I assumed to be interfering with the `cqo` instruction), then proceeded to `pop r14` after `call scanf` when collecting the user's input. Lastly, after `mov rax, r14` was performed, `cqo` seemed to function perfectly well seeing as how I no longer received the error with a negative divisor.

Answer (score -1):

Run the program with a normal user.. I was Installing a Software and got the same error "(Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)". I was running the program using root user and It was failing and giving that error. then I searched on the Internet and got no working solution. then I ran it using a normal system user and It worked for me :)

Hope this helps

Thanks!!